# 125+ confirmations, but Multibit does not recognise as Available to Spend

Tags: multibit

Firstly, Im a complete novice at this whole bitcoin thing. I bought 0.15 BTC from an exchange and they were placed into an online wallet that would tax me for leaving them in there. So i decided I would send them to my Multibit wallet that i had already set up. I entered the correct address, and Multibit is now showing a balance of 0.15 BTC, but it is unavailable to spend. At first I assumed it was because it was unconfirmed, but when i checked Blockchain, it says it has been confirmed well over 125 times. So how long am i realistically looking at waiting? Will it be an automatic update to my spendable account, or is there something i have to do to release it. Any help would be massively appreciated, as i really am very confused at this point.

Here is the Blockchain: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/19d5364d236b6d709e78b61eaf59c0c88155f76bb1241d3c89e8b82563a93421

Comment: I have also 'Reset Blockchain and Transactions' several times to no avail.

Comment: I think i have sorted it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer; I'm also a complete novice and I have an identical situation. How did you sort it?